# Returning a premade .json file from JSP/Java

Tags: java, jquery, json, jsp, jsonp

I'm trying to keep this simple as I'm not a Java programmer (yet).

I have a .json file written with the name value pairs. Currently, I'm getting this file through jQuery AJAX and parsing it with Javascript. It works well.

What I need to do is write a JSP file that will do a white hat validation on the server who is making a request for the .json file. If it passes the white hate validation, then either the .json file or the .json file name will be passed back to the Javascript to parse.

My question is: can the JSP return the .json file name or will it have to return the entire json?

Is this a combination of JSP/Java?

Again, I just want to use the JSP like a gatekeeper to get to the .json file.

BTW, I'm using jquery jsonp because this is going cross-domain. I got that working. I just need something on the JSP/Java side to do the validation and return the file/filename.

Answer (score 1):

You could return a filename and have the client load it, but it's generally not good practice (just extra, unnecessary work). You should pass the actual JSON object to the client and not just a file path that contains the object.

So, something like `{ "object": "this is a json object" }`

Comment: That is what I was thinking. I just have to find a straight-forward way of returning the JSON in jsp/java. I don't need to loop through databases or anything.

Answer (score 0):

If I read this right you created a jsp file that receives input which it then validates (and authenticates? ) and then if the input passed your filters you send JSON back the client.

If you are going to parse the JSON at the client-side it would probably be better to return the json straight to Javascript and not having to run through a lot of functions. But your question seems to suggest that you would like to return the file name that you have/generated (if I read that right), in which case you could return the file name and have Javscript read it with - http://api.jquery.com/load/ - presuming this is on the same Url ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting ) else browsers will block this for security reasons.

But you seem to have a good grasp on how this works, so If I misunderstood the questions please tell me.

Comment: No. I'm not using a form. I apologize if this sounds confusing. Here's what will happen...1.) 3rd party page brings in Javascript File A; 2.) Javascript File A then makes the jQuery .ajax call to the .jsp file; 3.) The .jsp file validates the Referring URL to make sure it is one of the approved 3rd party vendors; 4.) .jsp/java returns the file containing the json. Hope that helps. Thanks

Comment: Ah ok I see, ignore my answer then :D . But be carefull of referring URLS they can be forged so maybe rely on a api key and the url ? Just me 2 cents...

Comment: Again, an early thanks to all helping me. I appreciate your time to help.